# Создание объекта в куче с помощью malloc. Поля типа char* затираются

Tags: c++, c, указатели

У меня есть объект DoublyLinkedList. 
Создаю его экземпляр и применяю метод push.

```
DoublyLinkedList test;
test.push("C++_мультипарадигмальный_1_1983_check");
```

Та часть после которой всё начинает идти не так:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::push(char* parameters) {
        List_element* tmp = (List_element*)malloc(sizeof(List_element));
        *tmp = List_element(parameters);
        //. . .
}
```

Поля "нормальные" нормально и заполняются. Числа, логические. А вот char* почему-то ломается. Ссылаясь на тот же адрес (по крайней мере так Visual Studio говорит) значения в строке почему-то меняются на что-то типа "ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ"

Конструктор выглядит так:

```
List_element::List_element(char* fields) {
    char* iterator, *fields_copy = fields, *temp;
    unsigned i;

    iterator = strchr(fields_copy, '_');
    i = iterator - fields_copy;
    name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        name[z] = fields[fields_copy - fields + z];
    }
    name[i] = '\0';
    fields_copy = iterator + 1;

    iterator = strchr(fields_copy, '_');
    i = iterator - fields_copy;
    paradigm = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        paradigm[z] = fields[fields_copy - fields + z];
    }
    paradigm[i] = '\0';
    fields_copy = iterator + 1;

    is_compiled = fields_copy[0] - 48;
    fields_copy = fields_copy + 2;

    iterator = strchr(fields_copy, '_');
    i = iterator - fields_copy;
    temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        temp[z] = fields[fields_copy - fields + z];
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    year_created = atoi(temp);
    fields_copy = iterator + 1;

    iterator = strchr(fields_copy, '\0');
    i = iterator - fields_copy;
    description = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        description[z] = fields[fields_copy - fields + z];
    }
    description[i] = '\0';

    next = nullptr;
    prev = nullptr;
}
```

В общем, просто обрабатываю строку, в поле name записываю значения из fields. Алгоритм рабочий, даже не знаю в чём ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Самое большое подозрение на эту строчку:

```
*tmp = List_element(parameters);
```

Следующий юнит тест проходится нормально:

```
TEST_METHOD(Object_List_element_should_be_created_correctly)
{
    //Arrange
    List_element list_elem("C++_мультипарадигмальный_1_1983_check");
    char* name_test = "C++";
    char* paradigm_test = "мультипарадигмальный";
    bool is_compiled_test = true;
    short year_test = 1983;
    char* description_test = "check";
    //Act
    char* name = list_elem.getName();
    char* paradigm = list_elem.getParadigm();
    bool is_compiled = list_elem.getIs_compiled();
    short year_created = list_elem.getYear_created();
    char* description = list_elem.getDescription();
    //Assert
    Assert::AreEqual(strcmp(name_test, name), 0);
    Assert::AreEqual(strcmp(paradigm_test, paradigm), 0);
    Assert::AreEqual(is_compiled_test, is_compiled);
    Assert::AreEqual(year_test, year_created);
    Assert::AreEqual(strcmp(description_test, description), 0);
}
```

UPD:

```
class List_element
{
    char* name;
    char* paradigm;
    bool is_compiled;
    short year_created;
    char* description;

    List_element* next;
    List_element* prev;

public:
    List_element(char* fields);
    ~List_element();

    char* getName();
    char* getParadigm();
    bool getIs_compiled();
    short getYear_created();
    char* getDescription();

    List_element* getNext();
    List_element* getPrev();

    void setNext(List_element* next);
    void setPrev(List_element* prev);
};
```

Comment: в каждой книге по C++ есть слова "не используйте malloc"

Comment: Покажите объявление и реализацию `List_element`. `malloc`, конечно, нехорошо, но дело вряд ли в нем. А вот реализацию `List_element` стоит посмотреть - оператор присваивания.

Comment: @strangeqargo даже если очень хочется? Как это в книгах обосновывается? То есть malloc с объектами не работает?

Comment: Даже если ОЧЕНЬ хочется. malloc "работает" с объектами. но  C++ - это не C. Обосновывается это как минимум тем, что malloc/free не вызывают конструкторов и деструкторов. Т.е. ты выделяешь память под "сырой объект", под его "тело".  Кроме того, не надо использовать массивы char, если есть std::string, кроме ОЧЕНЬ веских причин (если вам нужно создать уязвимость)

Comment: @Harry добавил из .h описание класса. Нужно что-то более конкретное?

Comment: Т.е. вы не создаете свой оператор присваивания?! А в деструкторе удаляете `name`?

Comment: @Harry именно так. Оператор присваивания по умолчанию не в состоянии сделать char* = char* ?

Comment: В состоянии. А вы в деструкторе память по этому указателю не освобождаете?

Comment: @Harry Выложил полностью конструктор. Там надо бы вынести в функцию его часть, но пока так.

Comment: @Harry List_element::~List_element()
{
 free(name);
 free(paradigm);
 free(description);
}
ничего особенного

Comment: См. ответ, *Update 2*. В `*tmp` у вас **НЕДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЙ** указатель, указывающий на как минимум уже освобожденную память.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это еще не ответ - но в комментарий не влазит... не проще вот так?

```
List_element::List_element(char* fields) 
{
    char* it = strchr(fields, '_');
    int n = iterator - fields;
    name = new char[n+1];
    strncpy(name,fields,n);
    name[n] = '\0';
    //. . .
}
```

Но - очень хочется посмотреть на объявление и оператор присваивания `List_element`. По-моему, проблема там...

**Update** Оператора присваивания нет. Сгенерированный просто переприсвоит указатели. А если в деструкторе удаляется `name`, то после присваивания `name` в копии указывает куда? в, простите, хрен знает куда - пустое место в памяти...

**Update 2**

Смотрите код -

```
class Test {
public:
    Test()            { cout << __func__ << endl; }
    Test(const Test&) { cout << __func__ << endl; }
    ~Test()           { cout << __func__ << endl; }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test * t = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
    *t = Test();
    cout << "WTF???\n";
}
```

Это ваша модель присваивания `*tmp`. Как видите, созданный вами `List_element` благополучно после присвоение уничтожается. И что у вас в `*tmp` в результате?...

Comment: Как тогда следует сделать?

Comment: @Awethon купить/одолжить/скачать книги C++ Primer, Professional C++, The C++ Programming Language, или, если совсем лень, для разгона в  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/c

Comment: @Awethon Писать оператор присваивания с **копированием** строк, например. Или использовать `string` - они сами скопируются.

Comment: @Awethon Да, только не забудьте потом tmp освободить с помощью `free`, предварительно явно вызвав деструктор. Что поделаешь - такова цена отказа от `new` и `delete`: обо всем заботиться самому...

Answer (score 8):

Объекты классов с нетривиальной конструкцией не могут быть корректно созданы при помощи голого `malloc`. При надлежащем понимании вопроса, это может быть сделано правильно, но требует дополнительных целенаправленных усилий (а именно: конструкции объекта после выделения памяти), которых в вашем коде и отдаленно не видно.

Поэтому о чем тут вообще идет речь, мне не ясно. Ваш код в его нынешнем состоянии - мертв, неработоспособен в принципе. "Исправлять" там нечего. И чтобы начинать о чем-то говорить, надо сначала ответить на вопрос, что в вашем коде вообще делает `malloc`.

Comment: List_element* tmp = (List_element*)malloc(sizeof(List_element));
        *tmp = List_element(parameters);
Тогда что это такое? У меня всё вполне работает.

Comment: @Awethon: "Работать" это может только засчет вороха "взаимодополняющих" багов. Это только кажется, что оно "работает" - вы просто плохо тестировали. То, что вы привели выше - это попытка применения оператора присваивания к несконструированному объекту `*tmp`. Оператор присваивания не может быть применен к несконстуированному объекту, особенно если конструктор нетривиален (как в вашем случае). Оператор присваивания всегда ожидает сконстуированного объекта и, разумеется, всегда занимается освобождением "старых" ресурсов перед присваиванием новых.

Comment: У вас это, понятное дело, невозможно. Поэтому "работает" это только потому, что не знает, в какую сторону упасть.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно